# How to set BGR image to another image when black?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have 2 BGR images. One is mostly black. I want all the black pixels to be set to the pixels of another image.

```
u_v[:,:,:] = prev_frame[:,:,:] # Only where u_v[:,:] = black/(0,0,0)
```

Comment: And by black you mean exact zeros across all three channels?

Comment: That is correct! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I think you can simply use a mask : `m = (u_v==0).all(-1); 
u_v[m] = prev_frame[m]`.

Comment: Can you explain what that means a bit more? Looks like gibberish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a mask of `black` pixels by looking for `ALL` zeros along the last axis `(axis=-1)` by comparing against `0` and then [`ALL` reduce](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) along it -

```
mask = (u_v==0).all(axis=-1)
```

Then, use this mask for `boolean-indexing` to select from `prev_frame` and assign into `u_v` -

```
u_v[mask] = prev_frame[mask]
```

**Explanation with a sample run**

1] Inputs :

```
In [148]: u_v
Out[148]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0], # first pixel set as all zeros for testing
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 2, 2],
        [0, 3, 1]]])

In [149]: prev_frame
Out[149]: 
array([[[0, 2, 1], <== this one is to be copied over to u_v
        [3, 1, 0]],

       [[2, 2, 3],
        [2, 0, 1]]])
```

2] Mask of black pixels :

```
In [150]: mask = (u_v==0).all(axis=-1)

In [151]: mask
Out[151]: 
array([[ True, False], # first element is True as first pix was black
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

3] Boolean-index to select and assign :

```
In [152]: u_v[mask] = prev_frame[mask]

In [153]: u_v
Out[153]: 
array([[[0, 2, 1], <=== copied from prev_frame
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 2, 2],
        [0, 3, 1]]])
```